# How to properly align my relaxed molecule onto my gold electrode?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, computational-physics, physical-chemistry, rotation

the question is described below since it can be considered a chemistry or physics question: [How to translate from one plane to another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3208007/) originally posted on mathematics SE

> I am trying to get Molecule X (from a xyz file which carries x y and z coordinates of X) to be sandwiched between gold electrodes as shown below:
>
> [image: Sandwiched molecule X]
>
> So far I was able, with a python code, to align X using the rotation matrix Rz.
>   **Please not that the images are from VESTA capable of visualization only (otherwise i would not ask the question at all)**
>
> I got the following:
>
> [image: Aligned molecule Y]
>
> So both X and Y have the same orientation but I am not sure how to properly translate or move X to Y position.
>   In other words I need to sandwich Y around the same gold electrodes X was sandwiched. What I can say is that the yellow balls in X and Y should be the same! However i am not sure what mathematical formulation is needed to move the aligned molecule thus I am here asking for assistance.
>
> So in summary I want to go from starting point to ending point as shown below:
>
> [image: Merged figures]
>
> Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you need rather software to do edits in the definition files for molecules. Try here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_program_for_editing_molecular_replacement_PDB_models

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecule_editor